# Get difference between date returns zero

Tags: php, datetime

I have a date time in 'Y-m-d H:i:s', and i tried to substract the now date with the defined date +1 day to get remaining time in hours, minutes and seconds:

```
$time = '2017-10-05 14:54:03';
$now =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$endTransaction = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time. ' + 1 day'));
$dteDiff  = $endTransaction - $now;
echo $dteDiff;
```

but i always get 0 as the result

Comment: This is not SQL mate, you basicly are trying to diff strings.

Comment: Try using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects instead.

Comment: And the Datetime diff function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. The `date` function returns string so PHP is not able to compare anything. Try with the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.datetime.php) class instead. Its [diff](http://php.net/manual/pl/datetime.diff.php) method returns the [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/pl/class.dateinterval.php) object with some public properties, like the `days` property among others, which is the positive integer number (rounded down) of days between two dates:

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$endTransaction = (new \DateTime('2017-12-05 14:54:03'))->modify('+1 day');

$diff = $endTransaction->diff($now);

printf(
    'Difference in days: %d, hours: %d, minutes: %d, seconds: %d',
     $diff->days,
     $diff->h,
     $diff->m,
     $diff->s
);
```

Comment: i want to the endTransaction is from defined variable + 1 day

Comment: I've edited my answer. Next time please look up the docs how to manipulate the the DateTime objects. The official documentation is plain simple.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use this [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)

```
    $time = '2017-10-05 14:54:03';
    $now =  date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $endTransaction = date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time. ' + 1 day')));
    $dteDiff  = date_diff($now, $endTransaction);
    $date = new DateTime($dteDiff);

    $result = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: i got this error Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to string

Comment: at $now or $endtransaction

Comment: when i try to concat the $dteDiff with string

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description please try executing following code snippet as a solution to it.

```
    $time = '2017-10-05 14:54:03';
    $now =  strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $endTransaction = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time. ' + 1 day')));
    $dteDiff  = ($endTransaction - $now)/(24*60*60);
    echo round($dteDiff);
```

Comment: Unnecessarily overcomplex and inefficient example.

Answer (score 0):

`$endTransaction` and `$now` are strings.

```
$time = '2017-10-05 14:54:03';
$now =  date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$endTransaction = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time. ' + 1 day'));
echo($endTransaction."\n");
echo($now."\n");

It prints:

2017-10-06 14:54:03
2017-10-05 11:45:39
```

The subtraction is not a valid operation for strings. It can handle only numbers. The strings above are [converted to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). The conversion uses only the leftmost digits present in the string, until it reaches the first character that is not a digit.

Both strings above produce `2017` when they are converted to numbers and their difference is, of course, `0`.

---

The easiest way to work with dates in PHP is to use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and its related classes.

```
// Convert the input string to a DateTime object
$then = new DateTime('2017-10-05 14:54:03');
// Add 1 day
$then->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
// Get the current date and time
$now  = new DateTime('now');
// Compute the difference; it is a DateInterval object
$diff = $now->diff($then);

// Display the dates and the difference
echo('Then: '.$then->format("Y-m-d H:i:s\n"));
echo('Now : '.$now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s\n"));
echo('Remaining: '.$diff->format("%R%a days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds.\n"));
```

The output:

```
Then: 2017-10-06 14:54:03
Now : 2017-10-05 12:36:25
Remaining: +1 days, 2 hours, 17 minutes, 38 seconds.
```